How do I edit my Apps Script code so it creates a timestamp only when a certain column is edited
I have been using the following code on Apps Script on google sheets which successfully adds a timestamp to column A whenever any cell on that row is edited.
I copied the code from point 4 of this wikihow article and just changed M to A
(I can't copy and paste it in here due to the formatting)
(https://www.wikihow.com/Google-Sheets-How-to-Insert-Time-in-Cell-Automatically)
How do I change this code so that it only adds the timetstamp if the cell in column B on that row is edited? I don't know much about this stuff and can't work out how to effectively change the range.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
See How do I ask a good question?

To make the script only update the timestamp when column B is edited, add a test for e.range.columnStart, like this:
'use strict';

/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user manually edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/13045193.');
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 2) return;
  let sheet;
  if (!(sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName().match(/./i)) return;
  sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1)
    .setValue(new Date())
    .setNumberFormat('yyyy-MM-dd h:mm');
}

To choose the sheets to timestamp, edit the /./i regular expression.
The script above observes onEdit(e) best practices unlike the code linked to by the question.
